# php get empty directory modification time?

Tags: php

I can get directory modification time with recursive method (`scandir`), but if directory was empty or new empty directory was created by `mkdir`:

```
mkdir('newdir');
// how get 'newdir' modification time
```

I search similar posts and google pages but problem not solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php):

```
echo date ('F d Y H:i:s', filemtime('newdir'));
```